# Copy the name of multiple worksheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have created a "master" sheet which contains data from multiple sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3). Now I want to insert in column B (in Master sheet) the name of the sheets from where the data is coming from. I have an example below

Master sheet

[image]

This is the code I have so far for the merged sheets:

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, c As Range, x As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
    x = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            With sh
                Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(Rws, "A"))
                For Each c In Rng.Cells
                   
                    If Left(c.Value, 3) = "ABC" Then
                        c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(x, "A")
                        x = x + 1
                    End If
                Next c
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: `sh.Name` is the worksheet name.... just write that to the cell in question, `ws.Cells(x, "B").Value = sh.Name`. Also, why are you copying the entire row? Do you need the entire row, or just the data in column A?

Comment: Paste in column `b` like: `c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(x, "B")` and then write your worksheet `ws.cells(x,"A").value = sh.name`.

Comment: @JNevill - but one can't paste an entire row starting in column B, it won't fit. Regardless, I think the data is supposed to go to column A and the sheet name to B, seems like your comment has them swapped.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! You are right BigBen

Comment: @BigBen- Good observation, I have just fixed it! Sorry, I m pretty new at this :)